# primefaces datatable with List<Object[]> source value fails to sort

Tags: sorting, jsf, primefaces, datatable

I'm trying to sort a datatable passing a List as value to it, from the DAO, as in the next code, but it fails to sort. Am I ommiting something obvious?:

```
<p:dataTable id="mytable" var="item"
 value="#{backBean.items}" 
 paginator="false"
 styleClass="mytableClass"
 >

 <p:column headerText="field4" sortBy="#{item[4]}">
   <h:outputText value="#{item[4]}">
     <f:convertNumber maxFractionDigits="1" >
     </f:convertNumber>
   </h:outputText>
 </p:column>  
...
...
```

The code for the getter of the "items" property in the @ViewScoped backBean is:

```
void List<Object[]> getItems(){
   if(items==null)
       items = itemsDAO.findItem();
   return items;
}
```

where *itemsDAO.findItem()* is the JPA query returning my *list* with which i'm feeding my datatable.

When I click in the 'sort' arrows,  it's failing at sorting my table, and the page hangs with a neverending loader displaying at the bottom. To add some clarity, the *item[4]* contains a BigDecimal, and as I have read, it may be neccesary to implement some 'sortFunction' for types another than String or Integer.. is that right? Sorry if i'm not being too clear, it's my second post here, just let me know if I'm skipping some rule. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This works for me

```
<p:dataTable id="mytable" var="item"
     value="#{backBean.getAsList(4)}" 
     paginator="false"
     styleClass="mytableClass"
     sortOrder="desc"
>

 <p:column headerText="field4" sortBy="#{item.myID}">
   <h:outputText value="#{item.name}">
     <f:convertNumber maxFractionDigits="1" >
     </f:convertNumber>
   </h:outputText>
 </p:column>
```

And I guess the model have an attribute called "myID" and this is a number (just an example obviously)

Important: the datatable need a List for make sort comparation, so please implement the next snipped

```
    public List<MyObject> getList(int i){
        return Arrays.asList(items.get(i)); //Convert array Object to List
    }
```

I hope this useful! Regards!